# Stored Procedure: Update Int field passing in a Column parameter

Tags: sql, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I am trying to update a int field while passing in a column parameter. This works successfully when I try to input a varchar, float or money field, but not for int.  I get this error when I try to execute this SP with an int value:

> Error converting data type varchar to int.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUpdateField]
 @strOrderNumber nvarchar(50)
, @strField nvarchar(50)
, @strValue nvarchar(50)

AS
Declare 
@sql nvarchar (1000);
set @sql = 'update tblOrder 
SET ' + @strField + ' = ''' + @strValue + '''
WHERE strOrderNumber = ''' + @strOrderNumber + '''' ;

exec sp_executesql @sql;

GO
```

`

Comment: What are you passing into the stored procedure arguments? The opposite happens for me, that is I get an error only when trying to convert non-integer numerical values.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @datatype varchar(max)
SELECT @datatype = DATA_TYPE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
     TABLE_NAME = 'tblOrder' AND 
     COLUMN_NAME = @strField 

if @dataType = 'int' or @datatype = 'float' Or @datatype = 'tinyInt'
BEGIN 
  Declare @sql nvarchar (1000);
  set @sql = 'update tblOrder 
  SET ' + @strField + ' = '  + @strValue 
  WHERE strOrderNumber = ''' + @strOrderNumber + '''' ;

  exec sp_executesql @sql;
END 
ELSE
  Declare @sql nvarchar (1000);
  set @sql = 'update tblOrder 
  SET ' + @strField + ' = ''' + @strValue + '''
  WHERE strOrderNumber = ''' + @strOrderNumber + '''' ;

  exec sp_executesql @sql;
END
```

One way would be to fill in the @dataTypes as needed or put them into a table and use an if statement to pick the proper query.